# Show a grabber in a WPF StatusBar?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In WPF, how do I display a grabber (the mall dotted triangle in the lower right corner) in a StatusBar control? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below will work with or without a StatusBar control.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResizeWithGrip;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not a single line in xaml? ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip"

Comment: Accepted the answer, with +1 for Lukas' suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The grabber is on the top level window, not a property on the statusbar.

```
<Window x:Class="msbuildrefactor.MainWindow"
    ...
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
```